# Unable to resolve xml drawable files

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

this is the issue, all the attributes are suddenly invisible in xml file
[image: drawable file converted to something else]

[image: getting unknown attribute in the layout file]

I'm also unable to edit the layout file getting unknown attribute warning in the xml file

Comment: Those are binary XML drawables. You need to use plaintext XML.

Comment: plaintext XML is converted to this automatically, i don't know why that happened

Comment: Where are you seeing those XML? You cut the path off.